How to allow guest user to upload files
I have created a LWC component to create cases with files from an experience site and I have allowed guest user access.
To allow guest user to upload files I have enabled the 'Allow site guest users to upload files' setting from setup. Please refer below image

I have added the LWC component into a tab and tested it is attaching files into the related record.
I have uploaded the same component into the site but it's showing an error that the list has no rows:
15:26:32.0 (425967252)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[57]|Aggregations:0|SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :tmpVar1
15:26:32.0 (425989613)|LIMIT_USAGE|[57]|SOQL|1|100
15:26:32.0 (425994307)|LIMIT_USAGE|[57]|AGGS|0|300
15:26:32.0 (441783541)|SOQL_EXECUTE_EXPLAIN|[57]|Index on ContentVersion : [Id], cardinality: 1, sobjectCardinality: 96, relativeCost 0.033
15:26:32.0 (441799895)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[57]|Rows:0
15:26:32.0 (441823586)|LIMIT_USAGE|[57]|SOQL_ROWS|0|50000
15:26:32.0 (441841096)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[57]|Bytes:4
15:26:32.0 (441870586)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[57]|Bytes:0
15:26:32.0 (442012811)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[57]|Bytes:4
15:26:32.0 (442033833)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[61]|Bytes:40
15:26:32.0 (442184431)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[61]|Bytes:46
15:26:32.0 (442214175)|METHOD_EXIT|[16]|01pWG000000OMU1|FileUploaderClass.createContentLink(String, String)
15:26:32.0 (442345575)|FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

For testing I have added sharing rules for guest user on the case object. I'm not sure we cant create sharing rules on ContentVersion. what access I'm missing here. Please help.


<div class="slds-m-around_medium">
   <lightning-input type="file" 
                accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv, .png, .doc, .docx, .pdf"
                label="Attachment" onchange={openfileUpload}> 
   </lightning-input>
</div>

js
openfileUpload(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = () => {
        var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1]
        this.fileData = {
            'filename': file.name,
            'base64': base64,
            'recordId': this.recordId
        }
        console.log(this.fileData)
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
handleSave() {
const recordInput = { apiName: CASE_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields };

        createRecord(recordInput)
            .then(record => {
                console.log('Record saved successfully:',  record.id);
                this.fileData.recordId=record.id;
                console.log('After Submit',JSON.stringify(this.fileData))
                const {base64, filename, recordId} = this.fileData
                
                    console.log('Entered into files')
                    uploadFile({ base64, filename, recordId })
                        .then(() => {
                            this.dispatchEvent(
                                new ShowToastEvent({
                                    title: 'Success',
                                    message: 'Case submitted and files associated successfully',
                                    variant: 'success',
                                }),
                            );
    }

}

Apex Class
public with sharing class FileUploaderClass {
    /*
   * @method uploadFile() 
   * @desc Creates a content version from a given file's base64 and name
   * 
   * @param {String} base64 - base64 string that represents the file
   * @param {String} filename - full file name with extension, i.e. 'products.csv'
   * @param {String} recordId - Id of the record you want to attach this file to
   * 
   * @return {ContentVersion} - returns the created ContentDocumentLink Id if the
   *   upload was successful, otherwise returns null
   */
   @AuraEnabled
  public static String uploadFile(String base64, String filename, String recordId) {
        ContentVersion cv = createContentVersion(base64, filename);
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = createContentLink(cv.Id, recordId);
        if (cv == null || cdl == null) { return null; }
        return cdl.Id;
  }
  /*
   * @method createContentVersion() [private]
   * @desc Creates a content version from a given file's base64 and name
   * 
   * @param {String} base64 - base64 string that represents the file
   * @param {String} filename - full file name with extension, i.e. 'products.csv'
   * 
   * @return {ContentVersion} - returns the newly created ContentVersion, or null
   *   if there was an error inserting the record
   */
  private static ContentVersion createContentVersion(String base64, String filename) {
    ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
    cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64);
    cv.Title = filename;
    cv.PathOnClient = filename;
    try {
      insert cv;
      return cv;
    } catch(DMLException e) {
      System.debug(e);
      return null;
    }
  }

   /*
   * @method createContentLink() [private]
   * @desc Creates a content link for a given ContentVersion and record
   * 
   * @param {String} contentVersionId - Id of the ContentVersion of the file
   * @param {String} recordId - Id of the record you want to attach this file to
   * 
   * @return {ContentDocumentLink} - returns the newly created ContentDocumentLink, 
   *   or null if there was an error inserting the record
   */
  private static ContentDocumentLink createContentLink(String contentVersionId, String recordId) {
              if (contentVersionId == null || recordId == null) { return null; }
    ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
    cdl.ContentDocumentId = [
      SELECT ContentDocumentId 
      FROM ContentVersion 
      WHERE Id =: contentVersionId
    ].ContentDocumentId;
    cdl.LinkedEntityId = recordId;
    // ShareType is either 'V', 'C', or 'I'
    // V = Viewer, C = Collaborator, I = Inferred
    cdl.ShareType = 'V';
    try {
      insert cdl;
      return cdl;
    } catch(DMLException e) {
      System.debug(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}```


The problem is the in the FileUploaderClass. We would need to see that to further assist you, but in general, this error means that a query was written incorrectly or has the wrong filters.

Hi @sfdcfox,
I have edited the question and added the apex class. But the same component its working on tab for logged users.

Hi @sfdcfox,
Please refer the below debug working on tab
09:34:25.1 (304769797)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[57]|Aggregations:0|SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :tmpVar1
09:34:25.1 (315676539)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[57]|Rows:1
09:34:25.1 (315708245)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[57]|Bytes:8
09:34:25.1 (315735383)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[57]|Bytes:68
09:34:25.1 (315823058)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[57]|Bytes:8
09:34:25.1 (315837827)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[61]|Bytes:40
09:34:25.1 (315878554)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[61]|Bytes:12
09:34:25.1 (316165701)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[57]|this.ContentDocumentId|"069WG000001cOwoYAE"|0x6562a55e

Hi @sfdcfox, did I miss anything?
